# How to pause and resume the Unity desktop and retain its state

Tags: 16.04, unity

I'm working with Unity desktop. I need to execute a job that takes a lot of CPU time and Memory. When I run the job I want a clear RAM and free CPU so I stop the GUI using

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

and then start it again using `start`.
My problem is that all GUI apps (e.g. web browser) are lost in this method. Is there a way to pause the GUI, save its state (including all running apps and their state) to the disk and then restore it exactly as it was before?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I don't think so. You could boot in pure text mode though without starting a GUI to run your job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible but you can switch into console mode only to save some RAM and CPU for the process you want to run